# stop user to download file from server - JWPlayer + Coldfusion

Tags: video, coldfusion, jwplayer

I have an application and i use wowza server and hdfvr for video recording. I am using jwplayer for video playing on the site.

I need to know that how can i stop the user to download the mp4 file. Currently i am using a coldfusion which return media stream after authentication. Here is the part of code of file which return content of mp4.

```
<cfif FileExists(videoPath)>
                        <cfset fileInfoVar = GetFileInfo(videoPath)>
                        <cfheader name="Last-Modified" value="#fileInfoVar.Lastmodified#">
                        <cfheader name="ETag" value="#hash(videoPath, 'MD5')#">
                        <cfheader name="Content-Location" value="https://example.com/videoreturnfile.cfm">

                        <cfif structKeyExists(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'Range')>
                            <cfset rangeDownload(videoPath)>
                        <cfelse>
                            <cffile action="readbinary" file="#videoPath#" variable="theData">
                            <cfscript>
                                context = getPageContext();
                                context.setFlushOutput(false);
                                response = context.getResponse().getResponse();
                                response.setContentType("video/mp4");
                                response.setContentLength(arrayLen(theData));

                                out = response.getOutputStream();
                                out.write(theData);
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                            </cfscript>
                        </cfif>
                    </cfif>
<cffunction name="rangeDownload" returnType="void" output="yes">
    <cfargument name="file" type="string" required="true" hint="path to file">

    <cfset var l = {}>
    <cfset l.request = GetHttpRequestData()>

    <cffile action="readbinary" file="#ARGUMENTS.file#" variable="l.theData">

    <cfset l.size = arrayLen(l.theData)>
    <cfset l.length = l.size>
    <cfset l.start  = 0>
    <cfset l.end = l.size - 1>

    <!--- Now that we've gotten so far without errors we send the accept range header
    /* At the moment we only support single ranges.
     * Multiple ranges requires some more work to ensure it works correctly
     * and comply with the spesifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
     *
     * Multirange support annouces itself with:
     * header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
     *
     * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,
     * (mediatype = mimetype)
     * as well as a boundry header to indicate the various chunks of data.
     */
    --->
    <cfheader name="Accept-Ranges" value="0-#l.length#">
    <!---<cfheader name="Accept-Ranges" value="bytes"> --->
    <!---
      multipart/byteranges
      http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2 --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(l.request.headers, 'Range')>

        <cfset l.c_start = l.start>
        <cfset l.c_end = l.end>

        <!--- Extract the range string --->
        <cfset l.range = ListGetAt(l.request.headers.range, 2, '=')>
        <!--- Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range --->
        <cflog file="rangeDownload" text="#l.range#" />
        <cfif l.range contains ','>
            <!--- (?) Should this be issued here, or should the first
             range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
             we output the whole content?
            --->
            <cfheader statusCode = "416" statusText = "Requested Range Not Satisfiable">
            <cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #l.start#-#l.end#/#l.size#">
            <!--- (?) Echo some info to the client? --->
            <cfabort>
        </cfif>
        <!--- If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
            If not, we forward the file pointer
            And make sure to get the end byte if specified --->
        <cfif Left(l.range, 1) eq '-'>
        <!--- The n-number of the last bytes is requested --->
            <cfset l.c_start = l.size - Mid(l.range, 2, Len(l.range))>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset l.rangeArray = ListToArray(l.range, '-')>
            <cfset l.c_start = l.rangeArray[1]>
            <cfif ArrayLen(l.rangeArray) eq 2 and val(l.rangeArray[2]) gt 0>
                <cfset l.c_end = l.rangeArray[2]>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset l.c_end = l.size>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
        <!---
        /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
         * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
         */
        // End bytes can not be larger than l.end. --->
        <cfif l.c_end gt l.end>
            <cfset l.c_end = l.end>
        </cfif>

        <!--- Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct. --->
        <cfif l.c_start gt l.c_end || l.c_start gt (l.size - 1) || l.c_end gte l.size>
            <cfheader statusCode = "416" statusText = "Requested Range Not Satisfiable">
            <cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #l.start#-#l.end#/#l.size#">
            <!--- (?) Echo some info to the client? --->
            <cfabort>
        </cfif>

        <cfset l.start = l.c_start>
        <cfset l.end = l.c_end>
        <cfset l.length = l.end - l.start + 1><!--- Calculate new content length --->


        <cfscript>
            context = getPageContext();
            context.setFlushOutput(false);
            response = context.getResponse().getResponse();
            response.setContentType("video/mp4");
            response.setContentLength(l.length);
        </cfscript>
        <cfheader statusCode = "206" statusText = "Partial Content">

    </cfif>

    <!--- Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting --->
    <cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #l.start#-#l.end#/#l.size#">
    <cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#l.length#">

    <cfscript>
        // Start buffered download
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        // write the portion requested
        out.write(l.theData, javacast('int', l.start), javacast('int', l.length));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Here is the JWplayer code which i used to play video.

```
    jwplayer("myElement4859").setup({
                                    image: "path to image file",
                                    file: "/videoreturnfile.cfm?token=4859_129_AC4E46D8-5056-A85D-6EDDE334152C27EE",
                                    height: 360,
                                    logo: {
                                        file: '/images/logo_message.png',
                                        link: 'example.com',
                                        hide : true
                                    },
                                    width: 450,
                                    type: "mp4"
                                });
```

There is any way in jwplayer through which i can restrict that my video should play with my jwplayer plugin?

Or any suggestion through which i can make it more complicated for user to download the file?

Comment: Are you able to look at the request from jwplayer and determine whether it adds any special headers?  If so, you could filter based on that.  How many simultaneous streams can you support using this method.  I'd guess not many. If any video started going a little viral, all CFThreads would be busy/waiting.  You may be able to use conditional URL Rewrite rules to reroute to 403/404 page if header param is missing (and take ColdFusion out of this bottlenecked solution.)

Comment: We use ColdFusion (since CF3) and recently switched from unprotected media audio streams to use StreamGuys.com.  They allowed us to monetize (through subscription), protect, expire & limit to single-streams-per-user. We generate an encrypted token (which contains userid, window & timeout) and redirect to their media server.  The HTML-based ColdFusion app we wrote turned out much better than the iOS/Android native apps that a third-party developer created.

Comment: @JamesMoberg. I am afraid that jwplayer doesn't support any special headers. The main purpose of using this method is to run the video on IOS . IOS does require response that url is alive and then it starting playing the video.

Comment: ok... I don't think you'll be able to prevent downloading media files.  "Playing" & "downloading" both perform the same function and will download the file.

Comment: ok... i understand it.